# What's the best way to set up concurrent execution of for loops in Objective C?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a situation with a time-intensive for loop like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
   sum += dosomething(i);
```

The do `something(i)` calls are independent. This cries out for multithreading. Using NSOperationQueue on a two-core machine, I can do this:

```
int __block midpoint;
int __block sum1;
int __block sum2;
midpoint = max/2;
sum1 = 0;
sum2 = 0;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; ++i)
        sum1 += dosomething(i);
}];
[queue addOperation: operation];

operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
    for (int i = midpoint; i < lines.count; ++i)
        sum2 += dosomething(i);
}];
[queue addOperation: operation];

[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
int sum = sum1 + sum2;
```

It would be much nicer to have a single NSBlock and pass the start/stop values for the loop as parameters, but blocks used with NSOperation cannot have parameters. One reason this would be nicer is that the gymnastics needed to code for varying numbers of cores gets pretty excessive.

Is there a better way to set this up in iOS so a single NSBlock (or its equivalent) can be created, with parameters, and then called multiple times for concurrent execution? The technique ideally needs to be local to the method, and have read/write access to local variables (which is possible with NSBlock using the __block qualifier on local variables)?

---

For those coming along afterwards, here's the code, gleaned from both answers and several comments, that I finally used.

```
dispatch_queue_t coreQueue = dispatch_queue_create("coreQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
int __block count = 0;
int processorCount = (int) [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount];

dispatch_apply(processorCount, coreQueue, ^(size_t i) {
    int localCount = 0;
    int imax = (i + 1)*max/processorCount;
    if (i + 1 == processorCount)
        imax = lines.count;
    int imin = i*max/processorCount;
    for (int j = imin; j < imax; ++j)
        localCount += dosomething(j);

    // The results array should only be accessed from the main queue.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        count += localCount;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you seen NSEnumerationConcurrent?

Comment: I gave this answer some moments ago that may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168385/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-a-data-intensive-process-in-ios/24169811#24169811

Comment: I had not, really, but it won't work well in this case. The problem is not that do something() takes a long time, it's that max is fairly large. As I understand NSEnumerationConcurrent, I would have to synchronize fairly often, which would kill the benefit. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a concurrent dispatch queue.

```
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self doAnExpensiveOperation];
    });
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [self doAnotherExpensiveOperation];
    });
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // called when both have finished.
            // calculate sum here
        });

    });
```

Comment: ...but see the above comments about dispatch_apply.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the NSEnumerationConcurren flag:

Let's say you had an array of objects you wanted to iterate through, you could do:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
{

//do something

}];
```

[Here's the apple documentation on NSEnumerationConcurrent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW193/)

[Here's a link to show how well it profiles!](http://stavash.wordpress.com/tag/nsenumerationconcurrent/)

Using dispatch_apply:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_apply(count, queue, ^(size_t i) {
printf("%u\n",i); //Do expensive operation here.
});
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't see how this will work. I don't have an array of objects, each of which needs an operation performed on (or with) it; I have a repetitive task that must be done many times and the results need to be summed. Maybe I'm missing something. How would you code the above example using NSEnumerationConcurrent?

Comment: @Mike I would make a thin wrapper class that represents or points to the data needed for each iteration of the task, and then iterate concurrently through an array of this wrapper class. If that doesn't work for you, you could also try using dispatch_apply and a concurrent queue. Apple's docs explain that here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23

Comment: Thank you! I had looked at dispatch-xxx, but missed dispatch_apply. That let me pass a value into the block so the block could tell which part of the data to process. it was the missing piece.